# macro code working in one excel but not in another got issue in filter

Tags: excel, vba

[image]

I am getting error in filter.Error Sub Script out of range.your efforts are appreciated.I got error in filter.this work for one excel but error in another excel

`

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Claims").Range.AutoFilter Field:=33, Criteria1:= _
    ">=-.09", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=.01"


enter code here
```

Comment: Welcome onboard, Aditya. Posting a screenshot is not the best way to help who tries to help you. Please consider editing your question and pasting the code itself and the error message and on which line it appears.

Comment: Are you sure the active sheet has a table named "Claims" with 33 columns (or more)?

Comment: Thanks for reply.Sorry I am new on this.I am getting this issue on production.I am not able to see any Claims in sheet.But it every time contain 35 column ie fixed and only one column apply filter ie 33rd column name change in calculated contribution

Comment: Click anywhere inside the table. Then go to the "Design" ribbon tab and make sure the name of the table is "Claims" as this is the name you are using in your code.

Comment: Can I send you excel file

Comment: Upload it to google drive and post the link here.

Comment: its work fine for one excel but not for baby one excel sheet https://drive.google.com/open?id=1T3GXY8yvdCpcLDUulcQm1VASWAp3E-Ow

Comment: Don't forget to mark the answer that solves it to mark your question as "Answered"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must make sure that the active sheet has a table named "Claimed" as this is what you are controlling with your code. Or use another code to filter without using a table.

**Creating a table:**

1. Select the area of your table (manually or by selecting one call and
   the Ctrl + A) and then Ctrl + T (or Insert > Table)
2. Then make sure its name is correct. (from "Design" ribbon tab)

**Using a different code:**

```
ActiveSheet.Cells(1,1).CurrentRegion.AutoFilter Field:=33, Criteria1:= _
    ">=-.09", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=.01"
```

After checking the files you sent. You should use something like this:

```
Sub DeleteRecord()
    Dim MySheet As String
    Dim cnt As Long
    MySheet = ActiveSheet.Name
    Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.AutoFilter Field:=33, Criteria1:= _
        ">=-.09", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=.01"
    cnt = Worksheets(MySheet).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
    If cnt > 3 Then Range("A2", ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Delete
    Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.AutoFilter Field:=33
End Sub
```

Comment: now I get error on this Range("Claims[[#Headers],[Change in Calculated Contribution]]").Select

Comment: That is normal as this command still refers to a table object that is not there. If you chose using a different code, change it to `Cells(1, 33).Select`.

Comment: this not work.ActiveSheet.Cells(1,1).CurrentRegion.AutoFilter Field:=33, Criteria1:= _
    ">=-.09", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=.01"

Comment: In this it only remove data not rows.

Comment: In this it only remove data not rows. eg I have 6 lakhs record after macro it left 15000 records.but In my excel sheet showing 6 lakhs records 15000 records with data and rest empty.But I want it show only 15000 records.All empty row should delete

Comment: Hi I am again facing same issue substring out of range.your macro is not working.can you please look into this